# How to print the data from codeigniter in proper HTML table format?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Hi i have a Code that prints some data. But not the way i want to.I just want That this data is printed in table. Now the data is different for each day. the Scenario is i have a Data picker and dropdown. And now when i select a date and person from the list. It returns the login and logout information about the person's login and logout information. Also the working hours he was in office. and the time he left.

So Please help me how to print this in tabular form

The current output i like this:

[image: expected output]

I want the output in this way:

[image: expected output]

But have failed to do so.

This is my code:

```
<?php
        $loginarry = $attendances;
        $logoutarry =$attendances_logouts;
        $timeduration=0;
        $login_i=0;
        $logout_i=0;

        echo '<table border="1px"  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">';
        //echo ("Array Length = " . count($loginarry)." & ".count($logoutarry)."\n<br/>");
while(true)
{ 
    if( $login_i >= count($loginarry) && $logout_i >= count($logoutarry))
        break;

    if( $logout_i >= count($logoutarry))
    {
        echo ("<tr><td>Login[".$login_i."] : ".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data." and Logout : -----------------\n</td></tr>");
        $login_i++;
        continue;
    }
    if( $login_i >= count($loginarry))
    {
        echo ("<tr><td>Login : ----------------- and Logout[".$logout_i."] : ".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n</td></tr>");
                    $logout_i++;
        continue;
    }
    //echo( "******* ".(new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data))->format('U') . " **** ".(new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U'). "\n<br/>");

    //check if next login time is smaller then current logout time - if so skip current login time
    if($login_i < (count($loginarry)-1) && (new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') > (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data))->format('U'))
    //if( date_diff(date_create($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data), date_create($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data)) > 0 )
    {
        echo ("<tr><td>Login[".$login_i."] : ".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data." and Logout : -----------------\n</td></tr>");
        $login_i++;
        $timeduration += 10;
        continue;
    }
    if( (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data))->format('U') > (new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') )
    //if( date_diff(date_create($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data), date_create($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data)) > 0 )
            {
        echo ("<tr><td>Login : ----------------- and Logout[".$logout_i."] : ".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n</td></tr>");
                    $logout_i++;
                    $timeduration += 10;
                    continue;
            }

    //if more logout entries then skip to last logout entry
    if( $login_i < (count($loginarry)-1) && $logout_i < (count($logoutarry)-1) && (new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i+1]->date_data))->format('U') < (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data))->format('U'))
    {
        echo ("<tr><td>Login : ----------------- and Logout[".$logout_i."] : ".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n</td></tr>");
                    $logout_i++;
                    $timeduration += 10;
                    continue;
    }

    echo ("<tr><th>Login[".$login_i."] </th>:<td> ".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data."</td> <th>Logout[".$logout_i."] :</th> <td>".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data);


    echo (" <th>Duration</th> = <td>".((new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') - (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data))->format('U')) ."\n</td>");






    $timeduration += ((new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') - (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data))->format('U'));
    $login_i++;
    $logout_i++;

}
    echo ("<tr><td>Total Duration = ".$timeduration. " second(s) </td></tr>" );
    echo"<br>";
    echo("<tr><td>Total Duration = ".$timeduration/'3600'."Hours </td></tr>");


        ?>
```

[image: current output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution:

I defined the `<TH>` outside the while loop which prevented it from recurring

```
            <?php
            $loginarry = $attendances;
            $logoutarry =$attendances_logouts;
            $timeduration=0;
            $login_i=0;
            $logout_i=0;

            echo '<table border="1px"  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">';
            echo '<tr><th>Login</th><th>Logout</th><th>Duration</th></tr>';

            //echo ("Array Length = " . count($loginarry)." & ".count($logoutarry)."\n<br/>");
    while(true)
    { 
        if( $login_i >= count($loginarry) && $logout_i >= count($logoutarry))
            break;

        if( $logout_i >= count($logoutarry))
        {

            echo ("<tr> <td>".$loginarry->date_data." </td><td> Not Availabe\n</td></tr>");
            $login_i++;
            continue;
        }


        if( $login_i >= count($loginarry))
        {
            echo ("<tr><td> Not Availabe </td><td>".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n</td></tr>");
                        $logout_i++;
            continue;
        }
        //echo( "******* ".(new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data))->format('U') . " **** ".(new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U'). "\n<br/>");

        //check if next login time is smaller then current logout time - if so skip current login time



        if($login_i < (count($loginarry)-1) && (new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') > (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data))->format('U'))
        //if( date_diff(date_create($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data), date_create($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data)) > 0 )
        {
            echo ("<tr><td>".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data."</td><td> Not Availabe\n</td></tr>");
            $login_i++;
            $timeduration += 10;
            continue;
        }
        if( (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data))->format('U') > (new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') )
        //if( date_diff(date_create($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data), date_create($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data)) > 0 )
                {
            echo ("<tr><td>Login : ----------------- and Logout[".$logout_i."] : ".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n</td></tr>");
                        $logout_i++;
                        $timeduration += 10;
                        continue;
                }

        //if more logout entries then skip to last logout entry
        if( $login_i < (count($loginarry)-1) && $logout_i < (count($logoutarry)-1) && (new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i+1]->date_data))->format('U') < (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data))->format('U'))
        {
            echo (" <tr><td> Not Availabe</td> <td>".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n</td></tr>");
                        $logout_i++;
                        $timeduration += 10;
                        continue;
        }

        echo ("<tr><td> ".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data."</td>  <td>".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."</td>");


        echo ("  <td>".((new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') - (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data))->format('U'))/3600  ."\n Hours</td></tr>");






        $timeduration += ((new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') - (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data))->format('U'));
        $login_i++;
        $logout_i++;

    }

        echo("<tr><th>Total Duration</th></tr><tr> <td>".$timeduration/'3600'."Hours </td></tr>");


            ?>
```